# How can I format wordpress text code to be easer to read?

Tags: html, wordpress, visual-studio-code, formatting, formatter

I have this jumbled mess and it's so frustrating to format it so it's easer to read and to edit it. What extension I can use for visual studio code to format it properly? Before this I made page like this but it had much easer text for reading. You can see it in images. [old job with normal text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YAmBb.png) and   [jumbled mess](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yqqGW.png). I just need to format it so I can easer copy and paste same containers from one page to other so I can make this page faster.

```
[vc_column css_animation="fadeInRight" offset="vc_col-lg-7 vc_col-md-8" css=".vc_custom_1481407164519{padding-top: 66px !important;}"][cms_translate_horizontal translate="right" values="%5B%7B%22screen_size%22%3A%222400%22%2C%22height%22%3A%2250px%22%7D%2C%7B%22screen_size%22%3A%221199%22%2C%22height%22%3A%220%22%7D%5D"][vc_row_inner][vc_column_inner width="1/2" offset="vc_col-lg-5 vc_col-md-6"][vc_single_image image="1361" img_size="full" alignment="center" css=".vc_custom_1481341807195{margin-bottom: 30px !important;}"][/vc_column_inner][vc_column_inner width="1/2" offset="vc_col-lg-5 vc_col-md-6"][vc_single_image image="1360" img_size="full" alignment="center" css=".vc_custom_1481341833087{margin-bottom: 30px !important;}"][/vc_column_inner][vc_column_inner width="1/2" offset="vc_col-lg-5 vc_col-md-6"][vc_single_image image="1363" img_size="full" alignment="center" css=".vc_custom_1481341844557{margin-bottom: 30px !important;}"][/vc_column_inner][vc_column_inner width="1/2" offset="vc_col-lg-5 vc_col-md-6"][vc_single_image image="1362" img_size="full" alignment="center" css=".vc_custom_1481341852854{margin-bottom: 30px !important;}"][/vc_column_inner][/vc_row_inner][/vc_column][/vc_row]
[vc_row full_width="stretch_row" css=".vc_custom_1480577011869{padding-top: 111px !important;padding-bottom: 26px !important;background-color: #f3f4f7 !important;}"][vc_column css_animation="fadeInRightBig" offset="vc_col-lg-4 vc_col-md-4" el_class="full-right" css=".vc_custom_1480577601168{padding-top: 0px !important;}"][vc_single_image image="619" img_size="full" css_animation="none" css=".vc_custom_1479787850412{margin-bottom: 0px !important;}"][/vc_column][vc_column offset="vc_col-lg-4 vc_col-md-4"][cms_fancybox_single title="Interior Expertise" description="Team members will work hard to bring to life an original product. We prepare carefully the plan to get the demanded website." icon_type="pe7stroke" icon_pe7stroke="pe-7s-study" css=".vc_custom_1479886638628{margin-bottom: 93px !important;}" cms_template="cms_fancybox_single.php"][cms_fancybox_single title="Reasonable Price" description="With a good quality of website, Zookastudio also provides the theme for customers with a reasonable price." icon_type="pe7stroke" icon_pe7stroke="pe-7s-ticket" css=".vc_custom_1479886545694{margin-bottom: 71px !important;}" cms_template="cms_fancybox_single.php"][cms_fancybox_single title="24/7 Supports" description="Welcome to clients send their questions to us then we are ready to respond all of it every time with 24/7 support program. " icon_type="pe7stroke" icon_pe7stroke="pe-7s-headphones" css=".vc_custom_1479886984434{margin-bottom: 95px !important;}" cms_template="cms_fancybox_single.php"][/vc_column]
```

Comment: find an external formatter tool for your syntax or write it yourself

Comment: Welcome to stack-overflow .... your question not enough quality, please read help center, section `how to ask good question` here https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and you can get tour here https://stackoverflow.com/tour

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Prettier extension in VSC.